# c++ fork, without wait, defuncts execl

Tags: c++

Looking to fork a process, in c++, that wont hang its parent process - its parent is a daemon and must remain running. If i wait() on the forked process the forked execl wont defunt - but - it will also hang the app - not waiting fixes the app hang - but the command becomes defunt.

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    perror("Error with Fork()");
else if(pid > 0) { 
    //wait here will hang the execl in the parent
    //dont wait will defunt the execl command 
    //---- wait(&pid);
    return "";
} else {
    struct rlimit       rl;
    int                 i;

    if (rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
        rl.rlim_max = 1024;

    for (i = 0; (unsigned) i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
        close(i);

    if(execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "whoami", (char*) 0) < 0) perror("execl()");
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I fork the execl without a wait(&pid) where execl's command wont defunct?

**UPDATE**
Fixed by adding the following before the fork

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

Still working with my limited skills at a more compatible solution based on the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `wait` and friends wait until a process has exited, then reap it. You can call `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` to return immediately if no child has exited.

The defunct/"zombie" process will sit around until you `wait` on it. So if you run it in the background, you must arrange to reap it eventually by any of several ways:

- try `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` routinely: `int pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)`
- install a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` to be notified when it exits

Additionally, under POSIX.1-2001, you can use `sigaction` set the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` on `SIGCHLD`. Or set its action to `SIG_IGN`. Older systems (including Linux 2.4.x, but not 2.6.x or 3.x) don't support this.

Check your system manpages, or alternative the [wait in the Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html). The Single Unix Spec also gives some helpful code examples. `SA_NOCLDWAIT` is documented in [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

Comment: easiest solution was adding a signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); before my fork - I tried almost all the other options that seem beyond my limited skills. I'll keep trying just in case people want to use 2.4.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think a signal handler would be the best way as indicated. I would like to point out another way this could be handled: Fork twice and have the child exit while the grandchild would call `execl`. The defunct process would then be cleaned up by the init process.

Comment: i tried the double fork and it didnt work for some reason in my situation. double fork was also recommended in another stack question I had but generally felt it was not exactly the most optimal way to do this

Comment: I would agree, which is why I think the signal handler is better, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, double fork saves process from defunct state.

[What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

EX1: When client not exit, no wait

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ; //posix_spawn using environ that declare in glibc-2.xx/posix/environ.c
void main()
{
    pid_t   spawnid;
    char    param[64] = {0};
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/drive_server", param, NULL};
    posix_spawn(&spawnid, "/usr/drive_server", NULL, NULL, args, 
    environ);
    getchar();
}
```

EX2: When client exit, wait subprocess detach

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ;
void main()
{
    pid_t   spawnid;
    char    param[64] = {0};
    pid_t   sessionid;
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/drive_server", param, NULL};
    
    posix_spawn(&spawnid, "/usr/drive_server", NULL, NULL, args, environ);
    
    sessionid = 0;
    while( sessionid != spawnid )
    {
        sessionid = getsid(spawnid);
        printf("sessionid id %d\n", sessionid);
        usleep(200000);
    }
}

    //subprocess file
    void main()
    {
        setsid(); //detach
        getchar();
    }
```

EX3: when system have setsid command, no wait

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ;
void main()
{
    pid_t   id_spawn;
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/bin/setsid", "/volume1/drive_server", serviceName8, NULL};

    posix_spawn(&id_spawn, "/usr/bin/setsid", NULL, NULL, args, environ);
    printf("drive_server* spawn id %d\n", id_spawn);
}
```

there are 2 sources code can be referred to

1. util-linux-2.xx.x/sys-utils/setsid.c
2. busybox-1.xx.x/util-linux/setsid.c