# How do I run an Answer Set Programming file from a C++ File?

Tags: c++, ros, answer-set-programming

What methods are there that I can use to run an ASP file from the main function of my C++ code?

I'm doing  a project in which I am expected to control a simulated turtlebot using a C++ file, and use ASP code to construct an action plan that the robot can use to achieve a specified goal.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, SPARC (an ASP solver), ROS indigo, and gazebo.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? If I don't know why, I can't improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct that SPARC is implemented in Java ([this link](https://github.com/iensen/sparc/tree/master/SparcTranslator))?

If this is the case, there are quite a few options:

1. You can use [Java Native Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to interact with SPARC tool directly from c++ code
2. Other option is to create a [separate
   process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883462/linux-createprocess)
   from c++ code and communicate with it via stdout/files
3. You can implement [ROS node](http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes) in Java which accepts requests and uses SPARC as a library to process them. In this case your c++ doesn't care about exact SPARC implementation

Resume:

I would suggest you to try the last option. It's slightly more difficult than other 2 options, but it fits perfectly into ROS infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I went with option 2, using stdout (this is the option my supervisor recommended I use), and it worked very well. If you have the time, I would greatly appreciate your assistance with a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554833/how-do-i-use-output-from-sparc-solver-as-input-to-a-python-file